# How to calculate velocity time graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

[image: graph]

I'm not sure what to do. Do I break the thing into shapes and calculate each?

Like:

$A = 2\times 4\times 0.5 = 4$
$B = 8\times 4 = 32$
$C = ?$
$D = ?$

Also, how does the $14s$ impact this?

Comment: Yes, a piecewise calculation will work. The question is asking you to calculate up to the 14-second mark.

Comment: So are A and B correct? How would I calculate the next two sections?

Comment: Also, would I just add A thru D together?

Comment: Your calculation for A and B gives the correct number of metres travelled in each of those periods, yes. I'm sure you can manage the other calculations.

Comment: But C is not a triangle? How would that work?

Comment: @user416503 $C$ is a right trapezoid. Just as easy to calculate its area as for a triangle.

Comment: So if I add everything, then answer is 48? Is there anything else htat must be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: when the speed varies *linearly* with time, the distance covered is the same as if the speed was constant and equal to the average of the starting and ending speeds. Therefore $C = 2 \cdot (4+2)/2$.

(*In fact you already used this for $A = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 0.5 = 4$ since $2$ is the time, and $4 \cdot 0.5 = \frac{0 + 4}{2}\,$ is the average between speed $0$ at the beginning of time interval $[0,2]$ and speed $4$ at its end*.)

Comment: So if I add all, then the answer is 48?

Comment: No. How did you get $D\,$? Don't forget that the clock stops at $14\,$s.

Comment: I have A = 4; B = 32; I split C and D into seprate things - C, the triangle, is 2(4) (1/2)...D, the rectangle left over, is 4*2... Adding everything is 48.

How would you solve it, if this is incorrect?

Comment: `C, the triangle, is 2(4) (1/2)` Sorry, I don't follow this part, and it's wrong. You can see the right $C$ in my answer above, and all that's left to do is add $D = 2 s \times 2 m/s\,$.